# Occasionally “Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1”

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

There are a few similar issue on SO, but not my case, since it only happen **occasionally**

When I export a `signed` package using Eclipse, after typed all the passwords and passed to the final screen to  choose `Finish`, it then it say

```
Occasionally “Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1”
```

This only happen around 50% of time, and nothing need to be fixed, only retry again.

Anyone experienced this before?

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything but the only solution which worked for me is completely delete the bin folder, clean the project and export the signed apk then. But unfortunately I have to do it again and again... but it works anyway.